# Extending a linear action to monomials of higher degree

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, commutative-algebra, graded-rings

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $M$ be an $m\times n$ matrix with entries in $R$. $M$ defines a map $\widehat{M}:R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\to R[y_1,\ldots,y_m]$ by extending the linear action on degree $1$ monomials multiplicatively. I'm interested in recovering the matrices representing the linear actions on higher degree monomials.

Specifically, fix a degree $d$ and consider the linear map $\widehat{M}_d:R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]_d\to R[y_1,\ldots,y_m]_d$ given by restricting $\widehat{M}$ to degree $d$ monomials. For some fixed monomial orders on the $x_i$ and $y_j$, $\widehat{M}_d$ can be represented by a $\binom{m+d-1}{d}\times\binom{n+d-1}{d}$ matrix with entries in $R$. I'd like to know how to find the matrix representing $\widehat{M}_d$ given $d$, $M$, and some monomial order (I'm non-prescriptive with the monomial order here because I'm not sure if there is a particular monomial order which makes the problem easier).

I can write a program that will solve this problem computationally, but I'm hoping there is a general solution.

Comment: The matrices are given by the symmetric powers of $M$. These are analogous to the exterior powers of $M$, which can be computed in terms of minors, but I'm not aware of a particularly nice way to compute them.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Thanks for your comment, but I'm most interested in the case when $m\ne n$ (sorry, I didn't make this clear in the post). Any idea how the symmetric powers generalize in this case?

Comment: My comment does not assume $m = n$. Taking symmetric powers is a functor: if $T : V \to W$ is a linear transformation it induces a linear map $S^k(T) : S^k(V) \to S^k(W)$ called the $k^{th}$ symmetric power of $T$ and these are the maps you're interested in.